# How to resize Android app icons without loss in quality

Tags: icon, resize, image-quality, android

I have designed a beautiful icon for my app but when I resize it for different screen sizes (mdpi – hdpi...) the icon quality drops to very low.

How should I resize it with no quality drop?

I'm using Photoshop CC 2015

[image]

Comment: Resize it as a shape. The quality drop you're talking about might be caused by strange proportions of the elements substituting your icon. Make sure that your icon fits the pixels on your screen nicely by manually adjusting the proportions.